# Extracting string before pattern with sed (bash)

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I need some help with sed to remove everything after matching pattern and remove the last `"."` if it exists..

Take this string as an example:

```
The.100.S02E05.720p.HDTV.x264-KILLERS.mkv
```

I want everything before the pattern `"S[0-9][0-9]E[0-9[0-9]"` except the last `"."`

What I want:

```
"The.100"
```

Does anyone have a great oneliner for this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you can pretty much use exactly what you had in your question:

```
sed 's/\.*S[0-9][0-9]E[0-9][0-9].*//'
```

This matches an optional `.` character followed by the pattern you suggested (and anything after it), replacing with nothing. You were missing a `]` in the question, which I have added.

Testing it out:

```
$ sed 's/\.*S[0-9][0-9]E[0-9][0-9].*//' <<<'The.100.S02E05.720p.HDTV.x264-KILLERS.mkv'
The.100
```